# How to Replace traditional Ajax Polling with SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

**What I am trying to do with SignalR:**

1- Setting the hidden field from a session UserID on page load and send this ID back to server's SignalR Hub to start the polling thread for given user.

2- Terminate the thread when user leaves the site.

Right now I am doing AJAX requests to server every 30 secs per user to check for new user messages.I Just want to replace it with SignalR. I am able to create the user level thread in a HUB when the users session is created by setting the hidden field on page load and then setting the session variable via ajax request so the new thread is not created for the same user again and again e.g **page refresh**. The thread is periodically checks after (15 sec) for newly arrived messages. The main issue is how do I terminate the thread created for a specific user when its session ends. Is this the right way to use SignalR ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like good design - polling is never good, not for this kind of problems anyway. It would be better if you could deliver the message instantly. Are you using multiple webservers? If not, then deliver the messages locally inside the application. If you are using multiple webservers, consider using something like RabbitMQ, Redis or similar to send messages between the servers.

Comment: Yes I know that the Ajax Polling is not good b/c every request open and closes connection with server that's why I am using **SignalR** to replace the same Ajax Polling behaviour but I am unable to replace it b/c SignalR doesn't allow me to work with session.It's basically for broadcasting messages to different clients.I am unable to figure out **how to do infinite server side polling per user with SignalR**, to show each user their respective messages.

Comment: I'm saying that polling isn't a good solution, and I'm talking about all those threads you are creating. It doesn't matter where in your application you are polling, polling are (almost) never a part of a good solution. That's what I suggest you remove and replace with delivering locally inside the server, or cross-server/app with, for example, Redis or RabbitMQ

Comment: Example: Client sends message to server, server stores the message in db, and then notifies either with an event, Redis, RabbitMQ or something else. Some other part of the server then instantly receives the message and sends to the other clients. The DB isn't directly involved in the message passing, it's more of a fallback, for example if a client has disconnected, and needs to be updated with those messages not delivered to him when he was disconnected